# Add certificate in websphere local truststore; Programmatically

Tags: java, security, certificate, websphere

I am using websphere 7. From its Admin console certificate can be added to trust store.

```
Security->SSL certificate and key management->Key stores and certificates-> NodeDefaultTrustStore-> Signer certificates
```

I want to add it **programmatically** through Java code. How can I add and remove it from that store using Java?

Comment: you want to add new truststore, or a certificate to the trust store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to add truststore in Websphere programmatically through Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Imran,

See if you can use the wsadmin utility to automate the agging of certificates, it's better to let websphere manage that trust store

[http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frxml_atsignercert.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rxml_atsignercert.html)

thanks,
dims

Comment: Thanks Dim, Can I get any link for Java programming?

Answer (score 1):

here an working example to get from URL:

```
wsadmin.bat -conntype SOAP -port 8881 -host localhost -username localwsadmin -password Mypass123 -lang jython -c "AdminTask.retrieveSignerFromPort('-host smtp.office365.com -port 995 -keyStoreName NodeDefaultTrustStore -certificateAlias MSO365cert')"
```

Add from file like this:

```
AdminTask.addSignerCertificate('[-keyStoreName NodeDefaultTrustStore -certificateAlias
default -certificateFilePath <file path> -base64Encoded true]')
```

Also can be done via GUI iKeyman or Java CMD **keytool.exe** (C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\bin\keytool.exe)

Answer (score 0):

[This code example](http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java) can help you to do it. It takes certificate from an URL and store it in a keystore.

Edited:

Also, take a look to [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may be able to do, If it can be done via a "Web" interface (i.e. via an HTML/etc. page), there is a way you may be able to do it.

Take a look at [Selenium HQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). I think that it might work for you.